Property value is reset before form is submitted
I have a statically-rendered EditForm, which is responsible for submitting a model so I can add it to my database.
@page "/Test"
@using Domain.Entities

<h3>Test</h3>

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnSubmit="@HandleSubmitted" FormName="CreateModel" Enhance>
    <InputText @bind-Value="@Model.Name"></InputText>
    <button type="submit" > Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private TestModel Model { get; set; } = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Initialized: {Model}");
    }

    private void HandleSubmitted(EditContext obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Submitted: {Model}");
    }
}

public record TestModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}

Here's the log output (refresh page, edit name, submit form):
Initialized: TestModel { Id = 9e8e339a-cccc-499e-9f1e-76883657530d, Name =  }
Initialized: TestModel { Id = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Name = New Name }
Submitted: TestModel { Id = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Name = New Name }

I was expecting the Id (9e8...) to not reset when submitting the form. I'm not sure if I'm missing some concept or if I did not set up the form correctly. I want to find a proper way to submit the form with a valid Id.
I tried adding the Id as an editable field before and that seemed to resolve the issue - it wasn't submitting the empty guid anymore. However, I wouldn't like to expose the Id to the end-user at this stage. I don't suppose having that Id input field and setting it to hidden is the actual way to go?

You have to submit the Id value to server to bind to Model. You could bind like following when using Guid type.
<EditForm Model="@Model" OnSubmit="@HandleSubmitted" FormName="CreateModel" Enhance>
    <input name="Model.Id" value="@Model.Id" type="hidden"/>
    <InputText @bind-Value="@Model.Name"></InputText>
    <button type="submit" > Submit</button>
</EditForm>

Another thing you could try is using "Form" instead of "EditForm", because it refresh the page when submit. So it will be possible to save id to session storage with some encryption and retrieve the data when page is refreshed.
--update--
You could try add a encryptedId field to submit. Calculate the encryptedId before submit using javascript, then check if it is matching after submit.
    public record TestModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        public string encryptedId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    }

Trigger "addEncrypt" on submit button click, before the editform is submitted.
@page "/"
@using System.Security.Cryptography
@using System.Text

<EditForm id="myform" Model="@Model" OnSubmit="@HandleSubmitted" FormName="CreateModel" Enhance>
    <input name="Model.Id" value="@Model.Id" type="hidden"/>     
    <InputText @bind-Value="@Model.Name"></InputText>
    <button type="submit" onclick="addEncrypt()"> Submit</button>
</EditForm>
<script>
    function addEncrypt() {
        var base64String = window.btoa('@Model.Id');    //convert id to base64
        var x = document.createElement("input");    //add a hidden field for encrypedId
        var myform = document.getElementById("myform");
        x.setAttribute("name", "Model.encryptedId");
        x.setAttribute("value", base64String)
        myform.appendChild(x);
    }
   
</script>

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private TestModel Model { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"Initialized: {Model}");
    }

    private void HandleSubmitted(EditContext obj)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Model.Id.ToString());
        var code = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        if (code != Model.encryptedId)                     //if the id is modified, the code will not equal encryptedId
        {
            throw new Exception("Id not match");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Submitted: {Model}");
    }
}

I used base64 encryption here, you could change to some other algorithm, and put the alogrithm js file sperately. If user want to change Id, he has to find the alogrithm and calculate the encryptedId.

Ah, so because we don't use bind-Value but just value instead, the user is unable to edit the value before the submission, and I don't have to worry about someone altering the HTML and submitting an altered guide? I will try this later today.

@Sheim Well, I don't think so. User still could change the id using F12. But there 's a small trick you could do to prevent to change it easily, I will modify the answer.

I assumed it would work for me, but I'm trying to use static server-side rendering here. Hence, two questions:

Do you think it's possible to do this without using the onclick method?
I'm not sure if there are any significant advantages to using static server-side rendering here. I just wanted it to be fast in the first place, but I'm wondering if this will ever become noticeable if the pages with forms are rather simple - almost like the example above.


@Sheim 1. I don't think there's another way to let you doing something before editform submit. 2. MVC is also server-side-rendering actually. You could add MVC to a blazor project. And there's a similar solution to your problem that you could use [bind(prefix=childModel)] in the controller to submit parentModel while only modify childModel values.
